# Is there any MySQL's stored procedure alternative in Apache Solr?

Tags: java, search, solr, search-engine, solrj

Actually I have already created Web Application that widely uses MySQL Store Procedure. Now we want to integrate Apache Solr in our Web Application.

In existing application,the Store Procedure takes **dynamic parameters** like logged-in user id combined with other complex query.

So is there any way/alternative in Apache Solr ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can index all the data in Solr and query Solr with the user id and all the other dynamic parameters.
Solr provides [DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) which allows you to integrate with DB and import data into Solr.
And Solr querying and filtering capabilities should allow you to get back the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that cannot or shall not be indexed - e.g. a companies structure within a LDAP system - but is required to filter the results - e.g. determine if a user may see the result - you can use [Solr's PostFilter Interface](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/PostFilter.html). However this is limited to filtering that way you cannot add results.

A contrib with several built-in post filters is [the spatial search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch). As example it defines a post filter named "geofilt", which you may use like this - if you have a schema that fits:

> q=your+query&fq={!geofilt sfield=store}&pt=45.15,-93.85&d=5

The post filter call is what is placed within the curly brackets.

This is a rather advanced topic, but there are several good write ups about it. I especially recommend the first one.

- http://searchhub.org/2012/02/22/custom-security-filtering-in-solr/
- http://hokiesuns.blogspot.de/2012/11/using-solrs-postfiltering-to-collect.html